# CSS Media Queries also changing in original css code

Tags: css, media-queries

I have created a website and added this line of code for starting media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    .title {
        font-size:32px;
        line-height:30px;
    }
}
```

But whenever I make a change on media queries, it's also changing the code in the original CSS file. How can i avoid this process. Because I don't want to change anything on desktop view. I only want to make changes on that `@media` screen. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. an you clarify what is changing where? Where is the above code located?

Comment: Are you using a CSS preprocessor, such as LESS, SASS or Stylus?

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in media query try with my code,

[Try my code in codepen](http://cdpn.io/oDElF)